# Facebook Graph API Explorer get page specific page feeds

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, graph-api-explorer

I use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to get some feeds from my facebook page. So I have something like this:

```
GET ->/v2.2/my_page_id/feed
```

which returns me all the feeds from my page. At this point everything is well, the problem is that it returns not only the posts I posted, but also the posts other posted on my page.

What I basically want is to get only my posts which are placed in the center column without the other peoples posts on my page which are placed on the left column.

If I try this:

```
GET ->/v2.2/my_page_id/feed?fields=from{id}
```

I will get only the user ID who posted the feed, so I guess I have to put some kind of where clause like :

```
/where?from{id}=my_user_id
```

Can anybody help me with this? It seems such a simple thing but I lost lots of hours to make research about this `where clause` without any luck.

Comment: you have to make another loop which check your user id exists or not while taking post from pages

Comment: Filtering is not possible. Look at the docs.

Comment: Thanks guys, i will make the loop. I thought that it could be done directly from the query without using the loop which is not very optimized.

Comment: You don't need to loop. See my answer.

Comment: I saw it after I've posted the comment. It's perfect. I use it already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use

```
GET /{page_id}/posts
```

instead of

```
GET /{page_id}/feed
```

if you just want to Page's own posts.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/

> `/{page-id}/posts` shows only the posts that were published by this page.

Comment: Worth noting here is the important restriction that neither endpoint includes public posts shared by the page (where the page isn't the author and is not tagged).